Send email using new Outlook
I open a UserForm VidEmailForm which gets variables ccPeeps, VidEmailSubject, and VidEmailLink.
This looks correct on .Display. However, when I hit Send it doesn't send.
I tried .Save which does save it to my Draft folder, but when I try to send that, I get errors.
I used the same code to send a default email. The only difference is the body.
Sub EmailforVids()
    ccPeeps = ""
    VidEmailForm.Show
    Dim EmailApp2 As Object, EmailItem2 As Object
    Dim Signature As String, xMailBody As String
    Set EmailApp2 = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set EmailItem2 = EmailApp2.CreateItem(0)
    With EmailItem2
        .Display
    End With
    username = Environ$("USERNAME")
    Signature = GetSignature("DART")
    currentDate = Format(Now, "yyyymmdd")
    If Time < TimeValue("12:00:00") Then
        xMailBody = "Good Morning"
    ElseIf Time > TimeValue("12:00:00") And Time < TimeValue("17:00:00") Then
        xMailBody = "Good Afternoon"
    Else
        xMailBody = "Good Evening"
    End If 
    With EmailItem2
        .To = "(redacted)"
        .cc = ccPeeps
        .Subject = VidEmailSubject
        .HTMLbody = "<BODY style=font-size:12pt;font-family:Aptos>" & xMailBody & ",<br><br>" & "<a href =" & VidEmailLink & ">" & VidEmailSubject & "</a>" & "<br><br>" & _
        "Attached Review Players if needed for .cva files:<br><a href=" & """" & "https://redacted.sharepoint.com/:u:/s/tccapps/EbkNE4bZpbJFp2TLvs4cI7cBm1FqQ8WhiuR5191aGXydYA?e=mrKvYs" & """" & ">x64 Player</a>" & _
        "<br><a href=" & """" & "https://redacted.sharepoint.com/:u:/s/tccapps/EUKwdQSAtkJDv7tAMn1jvcgB891TeE74yiUfRM4exVReRw?e=wplpxf" & """" & ">win32 Player</a>" & _
        "<BR><BR>" & Signature
        .Display
        .Send
    End With
    Set EmailItem2 = Nothing
    Set EmailApp2 = Nothing
End Sub


Maybe you just need to close the </body> tag?

What error do you get? The number and text would be useful to know

Edit the default email. Add bits until it breaks to isolate the problem.

No VBA errors, that I could fix. Everything looks good on .Display but just won't send. I do get an error message from Outlook if I save and try to send from the draft folder but it won't tell me why it won't send.

Ok. I commented out line by line and no results. I started looking around my Outlook app and realized it might have something to do with running Outlook(new) and not Outlook classic. As soon as I changed to classic, all the emails I have been trying to send, sent. How do I tell the Sub to use the NEW Outlook?

Well. I have answered my own question. Microsoft Outlook(new) does not support VBA so I will just use classic Outlook instead.

VBA is not supported by the New Outlook.
It IS enough to just have the old Outlook open as well as new.
Emails are sent correctly.
